# Speed and style of Math.max vs ternary operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, is it better to do this:

```
var h = th > ch ? th : ch;
```

or

```
var h = Math.max(th, ch);
```

?

Comment: If nothing else, for simple questions of speed you always have the ability to test it yourself in your hands.

Answer (score 16):

The second seems clearer to me as it's showing intent rather than implementation.

I doubt there very many situations where any performance difference would make any noticable difference and it's probably implementation dependent anyway.

Comment: +1 on that : with Math.max, people reading your code **immeditaly** understand what you are trying to do ; with ?:, they'll have to think at least for one or two seconds... If you have 300 lines of code, it's already a couple of minutes lost thinking with probably no good reason (except in some really critical parts of your application, this kind of micro-optimization is probably pointless) -- who said something about premature optimization, and root of all evil ? ^^

Comment: I think that was donald knuth

Comment: This is actually a factor when you are traversing 130MB Float32Array objects.

Answer (score 13):

According to this jsperf test, an if statement is the most performant.

http://jsperf.com/math-min-vs-if-condition-vs/2

However, I do agree that `Math.max`/`Math.min` is more readable.

Comment: Thank you. Using your test I got these results: `function` --> 7% slower, `Math.min` --> 1% slower, `if` --> fastest.

Comment: The function test isn't valid because it creates a function every iteration of the test.

Comment: according to another test that i just ran online, the ternary operator is only slightly behind the if statement, whereas math was slowest of them all. reading math might be more straightforward, but the ternary/if provides more detail as to why you are executing the statement in the first place

Answer (score 4):

Just tested it again

```
math: 751.833984375 ms
if  : 563.000976562 ms
?   : 484.864013671 ms // wins
```

Run snippet for your case

```js
const perfTestAmount = 10000000
function perfTestMax() {
    const n = 'math'
    console.time(n)
    let m = 0
    let l = perfTestAmount
    while (l--) {
        m = Math.max(m, Math.random())
    }
    console.timeEnd(n)
}
function perfTestMaxIf() {
    const n = 'if'
    console.time(n)
    let m = 0
    let l = perfTestAmount
    while (l--) {
        const r = Math.random()
        if (m<r) m=r
    }
    console.timeEnd(n)
}
function perfTestMaxQ() {
    const n = 'qst'
    console.time(n)
    let m = 0
    let l = perfTestAmount
    while (l--) {
        const r = Math.random()
        m=(m<r)?r:m
    }
    console.timeEnd(n)
}
perfTestMax()
perfTestMaxIf()
perfTestMaxQ()
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a JSPerf test which lets you test it on your browser(s):

http://jsperf.com/math-min-vs-if-condition-vs/13

My tests on several browsers indicate that Math.min, the ternary operator and an if statement perform similarly.

Answer (score 2):

On mono the JIT can inline `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` methods and provide better performance compared to custom, inline, implementations. It will use special instructions if available by the hardware. So one day if in JavaScript there's some JIT (Google V8 ?) probably it will be some performance benefit to user Math class.

Comment: On mono? Heh? We are talking about JavaScript here.. And JavaScript engines are another world than .NET

Answer (score 1):

For speed, there is no significant difference.

For style, Math.max is much more readable and therefore the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Math.max() acts exactly the same thing you wrote as first. It uses the ternary operator to return the max. So if u want to spare some nanosecond you may use the first way, in order to avoid a call to a function. However, IMHO, this difference cannot really affects performance, unless u have an heap of Math.max to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using `if` statements instead of `Math.max` is dramatically faster in Chrome by 60%. Ternary is slightly slower than `Math.max`. In these tests, I've precomputed the numbers used for testing to avoid just testing the browser's random number generator.

https://jsperf.com/math-max-vs-if-vs-ternary2

### Results

- `Ternary`: 67% slower
- `Math.max`: 59% slower
- `If statements`: **Fastest**
- `Separate function using if statements`: 67% slower

Even though this doesn't matter for 99% of use cases, it can be important in performance-critical code such as game engines or when processing large amounts of data.